# How to get the text of an "EDIT" control from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have read that I should only use `PostMessage()` to tell the UI thread to access the UI controls.

There is no problem in following this approach if I am for example setting the text of an `"EDIT"` control. However, what if I want to get the text of an `"EDIT"` control, if I send a message to the UI thread using `PostMessage()`, then `PostMessage()` will return immediately before the text is set into the buffer, so how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you use `PostMessage` in the first place? Is there a reason you're avoiding using [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetDlgItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `PostMessage` for this purpose for the reasons that you identify. `WM_GETTEXT` is a synchronous message. What you should do is:

- If the window is in your process, then you should use `GetWindowText`.
- If the window is in a different process, then you should call `SendMessageTimeout`.

Why `SendMessageTimeout` rather than `SendMessage`? Well, if the other process has hung and is not responding, then using `SendMessage` would never return.

There is more discussion of this topic here: [The secret life of GetWindowText](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx).